# how upload profile photo and display when click update button?

Tags: reactjs, image, upload, laravel-8, profile

I am creating laravel and react project and I want to create profile page to update data. I created form and fetched data from database. I want to add profile photo upload input with this profile data .When I update data,I received message it was successfully. But I am trouble when I upload image and click update button. Can you help me?

Profile.js

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from "react";
import Header from './../../layouts/frontend/Header';
import Navbar from './../../layouts/frontend/Navbar';
import Footer from './../../layouts/frontend/Footer';
import axios from 'axios';
import swal from 'sweetalert';

function Profile(props) {

    const [loading,setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [userInput,setUserInput] = useState([]);
    const [error,setError] = useState([]);
    const [userImage,setUserImage] = useState([]);
    
    const handleInput = (e) =>{
        e.persist();
        setUserInput({...userInput,[e.target.name]:e.target.value})
    }

    const handleImage = (e) =>{
        e.persist();
        setUserImage({uimage:e.target.files[0]})
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        const id = props.match.params.id;
        axios.get(`api/getUser/${id}`).then(res=>{
          
            if(res.data.status === 200){
                setUserInput(res.data.user);
                setUserImage(res.data.user);

            }
            else if(res.data.status === 404){
                swal("Error",res.data.message,"error");
                
            }
            setLoading(false);      
            
        });


    const updateUser = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        swal({
            Title:"Confirmation",
            text: "Confirm to Update Profile Data",
            buttons: {           
                confirm: {
                    text: "Confirm",
                    value: true,
                },
                cancel:"Cancel",
            },
            icon: "info",
          }).then((value) => {
            if(value === true){
                const id = props.match.params.id;
                const userData = new FormData();   

                userData.append('uimage',userImage.uimage);
                userData.append('firstname',userInput.firstname);
                userData.append('lastname',userImage.lastname);
                userData.append('email',userImage.email);
                userData.append('phoneno',userImage.phoneno);
                userData.append('address',userImage.address);

                axios.post(`/api/updateUser/${id}`, userData).then(res=>{
                    if(res.data.status === 200){
                        swal("Success",res.data.message,"success");
                        setError([]);
                        
                    }
                    else if(res.data.status === 404){
                        swal("Error",res.data.message,"error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }



    if(loading){
        return (            
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div className="spinner-border text-secondary" role="status">
                    <span className="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            );
    }
      



    return ( 
            
        <div>
            <section className="m-0 p-0"><Header /></section>
            <section className="m-0 p-0"><Navbar /></section>
            <section className="m-0 p-0 profileContainer" >
            <h3 className="text-center p-3 mt-3">Welcome to Profile<hr /></h3>
            <div className="row m-0 p-0">
                <div className="col-sm-2 mt-5 side"></div>
                <div className="card-body col-sm-8 shadow-lg ">
                
                <form  onSubmit={updateUser} id="user-form"encType="multipart/form-data" className="row"  >
                    <div className="form-row col-sm-12 row">
                        <div className="form-group profile">
                        
                            <input type="file"  name="uimage" onChange={handleImage} className="form-control" id="uploadBtn" /> 
                           img src={`http://localhost:8000/${userImage.uimage}`} alt={userImage.uimage} width="100px" height="100px" className="border rounded-circle"/>             
                        </div>
                        <small className="text-danger">{error.uimage}</small>
                    </div>
               

              
                <div className="form-row row">
                    <div className="form-group col-sm-6 row mt-4">
                        <label htmlFor="firstname" className="col-sm-6">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="firstname" onChange={handleInput} value={userInput.firstname}   className="col-sm-6 p-2 border border-primary border-1" id="firstname"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group col-sm-6 row mt-4">
                        <label htmlFor="lastname" className="col-sm-6">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="lastname" onChange={handleInput} value={userInput.lastname}   className="col-sm-6 p-2 border border-primary border-1" id="lastname"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-row row">
                    <div className="form-group col-sm-12 row mt-4">
                        <label htmlFor="email" className="col-sm-4">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" onChange={handleInput} value={userInput.email} className="col-sm-8 p-2 border border-primary border-1" id="email"/>
                        <small className="text-danger">{error.email}</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-row row">
                    <div className="form-group col-sm-12 row mt-4">
                        <label htmlFor="phoneno" className="col-sm-4">Phone Number</label>
                        <input type="tel" name="phoneno" onChange={handleInput} value={userInput.phoneno}className="col-sm-8 p-2 border border-primary border-1" id="phoneno"/>
                        <small className="text-danger">{error.phoneno}</small>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-row row">
                    <div className="form-group col-sm-12 row mt-4">
                        <label htmlFor="address" className="col-sm-4">Address</label>
                        <input type="text" name="address" onChange={handleInput} value={userInput.address} className="col-sm-8 p-2 border border-primary border-1" id="address"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-row mt-4"><center><button type="submit" className="btn" id="profileBtn">Update Profile</button></center></div>                     
            </form>   
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-2 mt-5 side"></div>
            </div>
            </section>
            <section className="m-0 p-0 footerContainer"><Footer /></section>
        </div>
        
     );
}

export default Profile;
```

fronendController

```
public function userupdate(Request $request, $id)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'firstname'=>'required|max:191',
        'lastname'=>'required|max:191',
        'email'=>'required|email|max:191',
        'phoneno'=>'required|max:10',
        'address'=>'required|max:191',
         'uimage'=>'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg',

    ]);

    if($validator->fails()){
        return response()->json([
            'status'=>422,
            'errors'=>$validator->messages(),
        ]);
    }
    else{
        $user = User::find($id);

        if($user){
            $user  -> firstname = $request->input('firstname');
            $user  -> lastname = $request->input('lastname');
            $user  -> email = $request->input('email');
            $user  -> phoneno = $request->input('phoneno');
            $user  -> address = $request->input('address');
            

            if($request -> hasFile('uimage')){
                $path = $user->uimage;

                if(File::exists($path)){
                    file::delete();
                }

                $file = $request->file('uimage');
                $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $filename = time().'.'.$extension;
                $file->move('uploads/users/',$filename);
                $user -> uimage = 'uploads/users/'.$filename;
            }

            $user -> update();

            return response()->json([
                'status'=>200,
                'message'=>'Profile Updated Successfully',
            ]);
        }
        else{
            return response()->json([
                'status'=>404,
                'message'=>'You Are Not Registered.Please Sign Up!',
            ]);
        }
}
```

I add default value to  image = uploads/users/photo.png

When I upload image this error was shown.

```
[object%20File]:1 GET http://localhost:8000/[object%20File] 404 (Not Found)
```